# Django, struggling to make a form

Tags: python, django, database, url, redirect

i have a bit of a long question: i really tried and search but i seem to miss a part of the tutorial i watched: i want to make a simple website that allows a user to enter a serial number, and then it redirects the user to a page with a question and a bunch of answers(as buttons perhaps) after a few questions the site will give a page that compares the entered results and the entered serial number with the pre-determined(entered via admin) values and shows a page accordingly. i cant seem to make any progress other than take the serial number and display the number if its on the database... thank you for reading i hope you can help me out.

views.py:

```
    class ScanView(TemplateView):
    form_class = SerialFrom
    template_name = 'websites/scan.html'


class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = SerialNumber
    template_name = 'websites/result.html'
    query = ""

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        self.query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = SerialNumber.objects.filter(
            Q(number__iexact=self.query)
        )
        return object_list


class Question1(TemplateView):
    from_class = SerialNumber
    template_name = 'websites/questions.html'


class ResultView(TemplateView):
    model = SerialNumber
    template_name = 'websites/questions.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = SearchResultsView.query
        object_list = SerialNumber.objects.filter(
            Q(Answer1__iexact=query)
        )
        return object_list
```

models.py:

```
class IntegerRangeField(models.IntegerField):

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, min_value=None, max_value=None, **kwargs):
        self.min_value, self.max_value = min_value, max_value
        models.IntegerField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {'min_value': self.min_value, 'max_value':self.max_value}
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(IntegerRangeField, self).formfield(**defaults)


class SerialNumber(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    Answer1 = IntegerRangeField(default=0,min_value=0,max_value=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)
```

forms.py:

```
class SerialFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    number = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = SerialNumber
        fields = ['number']
```

result.html:

```
    {% extends 'websites/base.html' %}
{% block albums_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<body>
  {% for result in object_list %}
      <h1>shoe.png</h1>
        <p> {{result.number}}</p>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'q1' %}">from internet</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'q1' %}">from shop</a>

    {% empty %}
    <p>nothing to show</p>
  {% endfor %}
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

questions.py , which should use the object that the user inputed, but cant:

```
{% for city in object_list %}
      <p>{{ city }}</p>
      <h1>shoe.png</h1>
        <p> {{city.number}}</p>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'q1' %}">internet</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'q1' %}">shop</a>

    {% empty %}
    <p>fail</p>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: You need to redirect the user to your desired page after the user inputs the serial number and you make a database query. The scope of your question is a little too broad. It's hard to answer with specific steps unless you share your code and show us what it is exactly that you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes i did that, now that i read it again i realised the question is indeed broad, my apologies. the problem is: when the user puts the input inside 'scan.html' it redirects them to 'question1.html' which can access the users input, but when they answer the first question it redirects them to 'result.html' where the comparison i mention should happen but i cant seem to access the users input {% for result in object_list %} {{result.number }} - the code i used in quesiton page doesnt seem to show anything in results page...

Comment: I haven't coded in django for a while so I can't quite identify the possible issue here unless if I could see the exact codes. I hope someone is able to help you out. Goodluck!

Comment: I don't see any form tags rendered in your html. You're supposed to have form tags and they're supposed to have a method of "POST". And then I believe you should have `<input type="submit"/>` instead of the links and they should be withing the form tags. Give the inputs a `name` attribute, which I believe you can access from your views. And then in your view, you need to perform a form validation in the view class and then save the form data to database. I haven't worked with class based views much, so I can't help you out exactly, sorry.
I hope someone answers your question. Goodluck!

Comment: @Waris thank you! i know python but im a total beginer at html so i figured it was something like that! thanks for that ill search class based views myself!